# Opening specific list in angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using the following code to try `ng-repeat` in angular. I need to show the list which I click. But when I click on the symbol <kbd>~</kbd>, it is showing all the lists.

How can I specify such conditions when using `ng-repeat`?

### HTML

```html
<div ng-app='myapp' ng-controller='cntrl'>
  <input ng-model="addy" />
  <button ng-click="add()" class="w3-btn w3-padding w3-blue">Add</button>
  <span ng-show='span' style='color:red'>The TeXt Is AlReAdY In ThE LiSt</span>

  <ul class="w3-ul">
      <li ng-repeat="x in names" class="w3-padding-hor-16">
        <span ng-click="expand()">~{{x}}
          <ul ng-show='show'>
            <li ng-repeat="Y in features[$index]">{{Y}}</li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### Angular JS

```js
<script>
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('cntrl', function($scope){
   $scope.names = ['Fruits', 'Veggies', 'Cars'];
   $scope.show= false ;
   $scope.features=[['Apple','Mango','Lemon','Grapes'], ['Tomato', 'Carrot', 'Cucumber'], ['Porsche', 'Aston', 'Dodge']];
   $scope.expand=function(){
     $scope.show = !$scope.show;
   }
   $scope.add = function(){
   $scope.span = false
   if($scope.names.indexOf($scope.addy) === -1)
     $scope.names.push($scope.addy);
   else
    $scope.span = true;
   }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls check it out

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('cntrl', function($scope){
   $scope.names = ['Fruits', 'Veggies', 'Cars'];
   $scope.show= false ;
   $scope.features=[['Apple','Mango','Lemon','Grapes'], ['Tomato', 'Carrot', 'Cucumber'], ['Porsche', 'Aston', 'Dodge']];
   $scope.expand=function(index){
     
     $scope.expanded = ($scope.expanded != index)?index:-1;
   }
   $scope.add = function(){
   $scope.span = false
   if($scope.names.indexOf($scope.addy) === -1)
     $scope.names.push($scope.addy);
   else
    $scope.span = true;
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myapp' ng-controller='cntrl'>
  <input ng-model="addy" />
  <button ng-click="add()" class="w3-btn w3-padding w3-blue">Add</button>
  <span ng-show='span' style='color:red'>The TeXt Is AlReAdY In ThE LiSt</span>

  <ul class="w3-ul">
      <li ng-repeat="x in names" class="w3-padding-hor-16">
        <span ng-click="expand($index)">~{{x}}
          <ul ng-show='expanded == $index'>
            <li ng-repeat="Y in features[$index]">{{Y}}</li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```